# Download Optimized Images from PageSpeed Insights

Tags: image, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

In the previous version of PageSpeed Insights there was the possibility to download the image files, css js that had been optimized by PageSpeed Insights. In this new version I no longer see the download link, is not there anymore or I do not see it?

Answer (score 3):

As you rightly mentioned, PageSpeed Insights "before" offered the possibility to download the optimized files after the test. I can not see this opportunity now with the new version. There is only diagnostics and so-called opportunities, but no longer the possibility to download the * .zip file with the files optimized by google.

Comment: :-) i guess they rehabilitate it

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no way to download an optimized image from Pagespeed Insights, I have created the tool [Insights Image Optimizer](https://freetoolonline.com/insights-image-optimizer.html) to follow the [stickly Google document](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeImages) for auto optimize image that can be passed the validation. The output is optimized for JPEG 2000, JPEG XR format. That helps to improve your page speed also has the better score on Google Pagespeed Insights.

For JPG format the image will be optimized by cmd:

```
convert INPUT.jpg -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip [-resize WxH] [-quality N] [-interlace JPEG] [-colorspace Gray/sRGB] OUTPUT.jpg
```

And PNG with this cmd:

```
convert INPUT.png -strip [-resize WxH] [-alpha Remove] OUTPUT.png
```